# Add Whatsapp function to website, like sms, tel

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp, uri-scheme

I have a website that a lot of people view on mobile.
I have link for : Call and SMS and I want to add one for Whatsapp, so a user can click the whatsapp link I create and start a conversation with me.

If this is possible can someone point me in the right direction on how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web link to specific whatsapp contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344476/web-link-to-specific-whatsapp-contact)

Answer (score 36):

below link will open the whatsapp. Here "0123456789" is the contact of the person you want to communicate with.

```
href="intent://send/0123456789#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">
```

Comment: Well this worked for me, It opens Whatsapp message box of the contact number you added.

Comment: this is working fine for Android, but not for IOS. do you have any idea on the code for IOS?  
whatsapp://send?abid=[address book id]&text=Hello%2C%20World!
this seem to be the code for IOS, but too look for the address book id in website is seem to be impossible,

Answer (score 20):

Check this link out 
[Launching Your iPhone App Via Custom URL Scheme](http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/use-whatsapps-url-scheme-with-drafts-launch-center-pro-or-a-bookmarklet/)

and more on the [whats up url scheme document](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)

I did a quick mock up and tried it on my iphone with a link like this from a webpage and it opened the app on my iphone.

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!">whatsapp</a>
```

I could not try to send a message as I don't have a current Whatsapp account sorry.

Add user name using abid parameter

let's say your whatsapp username was username then it would be

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?abid=username&text=Hello%2C%20World!">whatsapp</a>
```

once again sorry I can't test this.  Also I have no idea what would happen if the username is the actual user of the current mobile device.  eg. You try to whatsapp yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it and on my android doesnt do anything. Am I suppose to change anything in the link to reflect the phone number the message goes to?

Comment: Thanks. Im trying to figure out what my username is. Cant just be my display name. Im trying to figure it out f theres a unique name or something. I tried phone number but that didnt work.

Comment: On android does it open the app because there needs to be something setup called an intent on android this is setup by the whatsapp developers and I cannot find if they have set it up as whatsapp or not.  Also like I mentioned before I have no idea what happens if it links to yourself so maybe get a friend to use the link on their device.

Comment: im using the phone number for the username. so far it opens a browser window with whatsapp://send********* in the address bar

Comment: FYI, just tried in Samsung S3 with Android 4.3, it jump to whatapps after clicking the link and let me choose the target audience to share.

Answer (score 17):

Here is the solution to your problem! You just need to use this format:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=whatsappphonenumber&text=urlencodedtext"></a>
```

In the place of "urlencodedtext" you need to keep the content in Url-encode format.

UPDATE-- Use this from now(Nov-2018)

```
<a href="https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=urlencodedtext"></a>
```

---

> Use: https://wa.me/15551234567
>
> Don't use: https://wa.me/+001-(555)1234567
>
> To create your own link with a pre-filled message that will
>   automatically appear in the text field of a chat, use
>   https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=urlencodedtext where
>   whatsappphonenumber is a full phone number in international format and
>   URL-encodedtext is the URL-encoded pre-filled message.
>
> Example:https://wa.me/15551234567?text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale
>
> To create a link with just a pre-filled message, use
>   https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext
>
> Example:https://wa.me/?text=I'm%20inquiring%20about%20the%20apartment%20listing
>
> After clicking on the link, you will be shown a list of contacts you
>   can send your message to.

For more information, see https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/26000030

Comment: The address wasn’t understood

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by creating the following link:

whatsapp://send?text=Hello this has been opened from the browser&phone=+**PHONENUMBER**&abid=+**PHONENUMBER**

Thanks to:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/open-whatsapp-intent-with-msg-specific-contact/73903/4

I have tested this on iOS, Windows Phone and Android

Answer (score 2):

I just posted an answer on a thread similiar to this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357241/3958617

The approach with:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?abid=username&text=Hello%2C%20World!">whatsapp</a>
```

and with

```
<a href="intent://send/0123456789#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">whatsapp</a>
```

Only works if the person who clicked on your link have your number on their contact list.

Since not everybody will have it, the other solution is to use Whatsapp API like this:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567">Send Message</a>
```

- More details on this API here: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/26000030
- And observations on how to use it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357241/3958617

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`https://wa.me/YOURNUMBER`

where `YOURNUMBER` is without the two leading `00`.

For instance for +37061204312 you write:

`https://wa.me/37061204312`

This link seems to work on mobiles and on desktop computers.

To prefill the message with text you can use:

`https://wa.me/YOURNUMBER/?text=urlencodedtext`

More in the Whatsapp FAQ: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/

Answer (score 0):

[Rahul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28292972/2334352) gives me an error: *You seem to be trying to send a WhatsApp message to a phone number that is not registered with WhatsApp...*, even though I'm sending it to a registered WhatsApp number.

This, however works:

```
<li><a href="intent:0123456789#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>+237 655 421 621</li>
```