# Mobile website "WhatsApp" button to send message to a specific number

Tags: html, mobile-website, whatsapp

A mobile website can be customized to allow users to share a pre-filled message in WhatsApp to a manually chosen contact. As given [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012) it is done using Custom URL Scheme. An example:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
```

To call a particular number we use:

```
<a href="tel:0123456789">Call</a>
```

Similarly, can we send a WhatsApp message to a specific number (or at least open the chat) without user choosing the phone number manually rather it will be one of the predefined parameters/attribute values?

Comment: I have answered this question on the following page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451668/add-whatsapp-function-to-website-like-sms-tel/43114035#43114035

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How i get WhatsApp abid to compose a message to a specific user in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405872/how-i-get-whatsapp-abid-to-compose-a-message-to-a-specific-user-in-ios)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Format to send a WhatsApp message to a specific number (updated Nov 2018)

```
<a href="https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=urlencodedtext"></a>
```

where

> **whatsappphonenumber** is a full phone number in international format
>
> **urlencodedtext** is the URL-encoded pre-filled message.

---

### Example:

1. Create a link with a pre-filled message that will
   automatically appear in the text field of a chat, to be sent to a specific number

   > Send *I am interested in your car for sale* to *+001-(555)1234567*
   >
   > https://wa.me/15551234567?text=I%20am%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale

   Note :

   > Use: https://wa.me/15551234567
   >
   > Don't use: https://wa.me/+001-(555)1234567
2. Create a link with just a pre-filled message that will
   automatically appear in the text field of a chat, number will be chosen by the user

   > Send *I am enquiring about the apartment listing*
   >
   > https://wa.me/?text=I%20am%20enquiring%20about%20the%20apartment%20listing
   >
   > > After clicking on the link, user will be shown a list of contacts they
   > >     can send the pre-filled message to.

For more information, see https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/26000030

--

P.S : Older format (before updation) for reference

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=whatsappphonenumber&text=urlencodedtext"></a>
```

Comment: According to the documentation, correct link now is: ```https://wa.me/<number>```

Comment: this is only working for `Firefox`, not working on `chrome`, I follow the link 
https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/26000030

Answer (score 13):

WhatsApp is now providing a much simpler API `https://wa.me/` This isn't introducing any new features, just a simpler way to execute things. There's no need to check for user agent while implementing this API as it will also work with native apps as well as the web interface of whatsapp (web.whatsapp.com) on desktop.

This can be used in multiple use cases

- A **Click to chat** button : Use `https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber` to open a chat dialog with the specified whatsapp user. Please note that the `whatsappphonenumber` should be a valid whatsapp number in international format without leading zeros, '+', '-' and spaces. e.g. 15551234567

  `<a href="https://wa.me/15551234567">Whatsapp Me</a>`
- A **Share this on whatsapp** button : Use `https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext` to open a whatsapp contact selection dialog with a preset text. e.g.

  `<a href="https://wa.me/?text=I%20found%20a%20great%20website.%20Check%20out%20this%20link%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F">Share on WhatsApp</a>`
- A **Contact me** button with **prefilled text** : A combination of the above two, Might be useful if you want to get a prefilled custom message from users landing on a particular page. Use format `https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=urlencodedtext`

  `<a href="https://wa.me/15551234567?text=I%20am%20interested%20in%20your%20services.%20How%20to%20get%20started%3F">I am interested</a>`

For official documentation visit https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030

Answer (score 9):

On android, you can try

```
href="intent://send/[countrycode_without_plus][number]#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end
```

replace `[countrycode_without_plus][number]` with the number,

Answer (score 2):

**Official WhatsApp doc Says-:**

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=countrycode+phonenumber&text=urlencodedtext

Use: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567&text=urlencodedtext

Don't use: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+001-(555)1234567

https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030

Answer (score 2):

i used this code and it works fine for me, just change **+92xxxxxxxxxx** to your valid whatsapp number, with country code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var options = {
                whatsapp: "+92xxxxxxxxxx", // WhatsApp number
                call_to_action: "Message us", // Call to action
                position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'

            };
            var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
            var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
            s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: Refused to load the script 'chrome-extension://static.whatshelp.io/widget-send-button/js/init.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, there is not option to put number in whatsapp protocol. only is possible with parameter ABID (address Book ID), but you must have this contact with specific name to do this.
check [WhatsApp Documentation](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/es/iphone/23559013)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is useful to them who want click to chat whatsapp in website to redirect web.whatsapp.com with default content or message and in mobile device to open in whatsapp in mobile app with default content to text bar in app.

also add jquery link.

```
<a  target="_blank" title="Contact Us On WhatsApp" href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+91xxxxxxxxx&amp;text=Hi, I would like to get more information.." class="whatsapplink hidemobile" style="background-color:#2DC100">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-whatsapp" style="color:#fff"></i>
<span style="color:#fff">
    Contact Us On WhatsApp        </span>
</a>
<a  target="_blank" title="Contact Us On WhatsApp" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+91xxxxxxxxx&text=Hi,%20I%20would%20like%20to%20get%20more%20information.." class="whatsapplink hideweb" style="background-color:#2DC100">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-whatsapp" style="color:#fff"></i>
<span style="color:#fff">
    Contact Us On WhatsApp        </span>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var mobile = (/iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
if (mobile) { 

$('.hidemobile').css('display', 'none'); // OR you can use $('.hidemobile').hide();
} 
else 
{ 
$('.hideweb').css('display', 'none'); // OR you can use $('.hideweb').hide();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To send a Whatsapp message from a website, use the below URL.

> URL: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXXXX&text=dummy

Here the **phone** and **text** are parameters were one of them is required.

- **phone**: To whom we need to send the message
- **text**: The text needs to share.

---

This URL is also can be used. It displays a blank screen if there is no application found!

> URL: whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!

*Note: All the above will work in web, only if WhatsApp desktop app is installed*

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, the official documentation is available here: [WhatsApp.com FAQ: Android -> Chats -> How to use click to chat](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/).  The documentation states:

> Example: https://wa.me/15551234567?text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale

**BUT!**  Why don't we try copying that into a new tab in your browser and going there right now?

> https://wa.me/text=testtesttesttest

Results: ***ERROR PAGE NOT FOUND.***

[image]

*What gives???*

Fix it easily by using one of *THESE* format:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere&phone=123
```

*No wa.me domain in this URL!*

[image: WhatsApp send text page.]

Comment: You are missing a question mark in your BUT test. it should be like this:
https://wa.me/?text=testtesttesttest

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to send messages
method 1)  `https://wa.me/111234567890?text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale`

this will try to send using the whatsapp app, if app not installed it will try to use the web.whatsapp api

method 2) `https://web.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=111234567890&text=I%27m+interested+in+your+car+for+sale&type=phone_number&app_absent=0`

this is recommended for sending messages from a desktop environment where the check for installed whatsapp is avoided and directly sends using the signed in web.whatsapp account