# Pre-filled message to a Telegram number

Tags: telegram

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218378/mobile-website-whatsapp-button-to-send-message-to-a-specific-number/51721337#51721337?newreg=376ef2e0f0054510809e23490f9ee9d4) I found a very useful answer showing how to send a pre-filled message from a website using whatsapp.

Can we do the same with Telegram?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use open a Telegram chat with:

1. https://t.me/username
2. tg://resolve?domain=username

And send a message to your contact with `tg://msg?text=Text&to=+(user mobile number)`

*But sending not works for me.*

Answer (score 4):

All of these URLs should be valid...

```
https://t.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
https://telegram.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
tg://msg_url?url={url}&text={text}
```

**The official API documentation source: [Core.Telegram.org: Widgets -> Sharing Button](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/share#custom-buttons)**

They suggest the `t.me` format.  You may prefill the following fields:

- `url` : The URL you want to share.
- `text` : Text to accompany the URL you want to share.

So, for instance, you might have...

> https://t.me/share/url?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.revoltlib.com%2F&text=Revolt+Library

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#telegramme

[image: Social Share URLs]

Comment: Can a user be specified as part of the URI as well?