# Open Whatsapp Windows app directly from python program using url

Tags: python, windows, url, automation, whatsapp

According to this [FAQ page](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app) of Whatsapp on **How to link to WhatsApp from a different app**

Using the URL

`whatsapp://send?phone=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&text=Hello`

can be used to open the Whatsapp app on a Windows PC and perform a custom action.

It does work when it is opened in a browser. The URL opens Whatsapp installed and composes the message(*parameter:*`text`) for the given contact(*parameter:*`phone`)

I want to open the Whatsapp application directly using python script without the intervention of browser in between

I have tried using `request` and `urlib`, but they don't consider it as a valid schema for URL as it does not have a `http://` or `https://` instead it has `whatsapp://`.

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'whatsapp://send'
```

Is there a library in python that would open the associated applications directly based on the URL.

**P.S.** I know the page is for Iphone but the link works perfectly on windows browser. Just need to know if that can be used.

Working with `Python 3.7.9` on **Windows 10**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cmd exe to do such a job. Just try

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/C", "start whatsapp://send?phone=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&text=Hello"], shell=True)
```

edit:
if you want to pass '&'(ampersand) in cmd shell you need to use escape char '^' for it.

please try that one

```
subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/C", "start whatsapp://send?phone=XXXXXXXXXXXXX^&text=Hello"], shell=True)
```

Comment: This does open the Whatsapp PC application. But the command seems to discard the `&text` part as the chat window opened does not have the text pre-filled. While I could do that explicitly after the application window opens but would like to know if it can be done directly

Comment: You may try https://stackoverflow.com/a/49754020/2016727 . But it’s out of the scope of this question. You may accept that one as answered and create a new question about whatsapp application parameters.

Comment: That answer, as you said, does not fit in the scope of the question. But this solution also only solves half the purpose of the question.

Comment: I have edited my answer to solve the remaining half of your problem. I have also tested and it should be working as expected now.

Answer (score -2):

Using this command

start whatsapp://send?phone=XXXXXXXXXXXXX^&text=Hello

not working after updated to new WhatsApp Desktop App (UWP) for windows.

you have other idea for send text message to destination user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this document https://faq.whatsapp.com/563219570998715/?cms_platform=iphone&locale=us_us no work with last versione of WhatsApp Desktop