# How to open an e-mailer link in whatsapp for both ios and android devices

Tags: android, html, ios, email, whatsapp

I want to open a message in whatsapp for android devices through click via Email.

For IOS devices this code worked

```
href="whatsapp://send?text=blahblah"
```

Comment: not possible in android

Comment: Try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344476/web-link-to-specific-whatsapp-contact

Comment: It's not working in newsletter. But, i have found below code                            <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567">Send Message</a>

Comment: It's not working in newsletter. But, i have found below code  <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=whatsappphonenumber&text=urlencodedtext"></a>                                                                                                It's working only for Whatsapp web with certain condition. you need to keep the content in Url-encode format. Continue Read next comment

Comment: he message which i am using is basically a link, which includes a placeholder. And during send out this Placeholder picks up the value which has been defined as a variable. But when i use the same link in encoded format the placeholder is not picking up the value.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for my question.

you can share any text to a predefined number. The below method works for android, WhatsApp web, IOS etc.

You just need to use this format:

By using this format, you can easily send a custom message to a specific number.