# Auto update Msg In whatsapp

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website having whatsapp link on it. When click on WhatsApp icon WhatsApp app opens with chatbox. I want an auto written msg on it so that the user only has to press the send button. Plz, help. Thanks in advance.

HTML :

```
    <a class="english call-msg"  
       href= "https://wa.me/+911234567891" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"
      target="_blank">
     <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>Whatsapp
   </a>
```

Comment: I don’t know if you can with the short url, but try adding the query string parameter “text=your%20message%20here”?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web link to specific whatsapp contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344476/web-link-to-specific-whatsapp-contact)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a link with just a pre-filled message, use [https://wa.me/{number}?text=urlencodedtext](https://wa.me/%7Bnumber%7D?text=urlencodedtext)

```
<a href="https://wa.me/911234567891?text=hello%20world">Whatsapp</a>
```

Ref: https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app/?lang=fb

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an additional `text` parameter:

```html
<a href="https://wa.me/911234567891?text=hello%20world">Whatsapp</a>
```

or

```html
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=911234567891&text=hello%20world">Whatsapp</a>
```

or

```html
<a href="whatsapp://send?phone=911234567891&text=hello%20world">Whatsapp</a>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357241/10551293

https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-use-click-to-chat/