# Is there a way to add a link on my webpage that will say "Call now" and when it's pressed the it would make a directly call on the whatsapp?

Tags: html, hyperlink, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have tried this like the normal call link :

```
<a href="tel:321456789">Call Now</a>
```

But this isn't working :

```
<a href="https://whatsapp.com/tel:321456789">Call Now</a>
```

Comment: maybe go read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344476/web-link-to-specific-whatsapp-contact. I think that when API can be used to send message, you can use it to call too