# WhatsApp API (send phone)

Tags: whatsapp

Suppose that the site has a phone number and a "Whatsapp" button, which contains a link https://wa.me/phone number, when clicked, a new tab opens in the browser and the link is converted to https://api.whatsapp.com / send /? phone =% 2Bphonenumber & text & app_absent = 0, then a chat with a number in the desktop application opens. But sometimes WhatsApp returns 429 error, allegedly the number of requests has been exceeded. Although the requests leave no more than 10, with an interval of 1-2 minutes. Is this interval not enough?

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here, fixed with whatsapp://send/?phone= ....

Comment: This has several more implications. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357241/3325322 for more details.