# Open Android App from Web Browser

Tags: android, url, uri

i want to open 4 apps from my web page..

1. Google Calendar
2. Whatsapp
3. TickTick
4. My Effective Todo

i dont know how to do it from android browser!

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451668/add-whatsapp-function-to-website-like-sms-tel

Comment: @droidev give some code maybe? i just want to open apps?