# executing <a href> in a hyperlink

Tags: html

`<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hi this is a message sent from your mobile site&phone=+271234567890&abid=+271234567890">`

The code work perfectly, however, i need it to be execute when a HTTP link is clicked? if so, how would i go about doing it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451668/add-whatsapp-function-to-website-like-sms-tel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] before asking a question. :)

Comment: This question did bring some great value, before getting edited: "ladies and guys" as a way to refer to an audience

Comment: @Freeman [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989). Introductory paragraphs that do nothing but greet the audience are considered to be noise. It _definitely_ doesn't bring "great value"; in my edit I removed nothing of value.

Comment: I know man, it was a joke